# Get setting from phone directly

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, application-settings

How to make my code to set and get setting directly from page Setting in Windows Phone?

```
if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("LocationConsent"))
    {
    if ((bool)IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["LocationConsent"] == true)

        return;
    else
    {
        MessageBoxResult result =
                    MessageBox.Show("Can I use your position?",
                    "Location",
                    MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);

        if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
        {
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["LocationConsent"] = true;
        }
        else
        {
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["LocationConsent"] = false;
        }

        IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
    }
    }
else
{
MessageBoxResult result = 
            MessageBox.Show("Can I use your position?", 
            "Location",
            MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);

        if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
        {
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["LocationConsent"] = true;
        }else
        {
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["LocationConsent"] = false;
        }

        IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
    }
}
```

In this example I use location setting, then I realize when I set it true from my application it will change setting in page Settings to on too. But when I change my location Setting from page Settings in original Windows Phone to off but in my application it still readed as true. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
   if((IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("LocationConsent")) && ((bool)IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["LocationConsent"] == true))
            {   return; }
            else
            {      MessageBoxResult result =
                    MessageBox.Show("This app accesses your phone's location. Is that ok?",
                    "Location",
                    MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
                if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
                {IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["LocationConsent"] = true;  }
                else
                {IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["LocationConsent"] = false;  }
                IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();         
   }
```